# Decryption using CryptoStream returns an empty file

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm trying to use AES to see how encryption/decryption works. Encrypting files works fine with the following code:
(These methods are in two separate files)

```
        private void tempEncrypt()
        {
            // Creates file with "Test String" inside
            byte[] test = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test String");
            var file = File.Create("test.txt");
            file.Write(test, 0, test.Length);

            // Saves key and IV for decryption
            var temp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(temp.Key));
            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(temp.IV));

            Encryptor.Encrypt(file, temp.Key, temp.IV);
        }

        public static void Encrypt(FileStream source, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Creates a temp file for encrypting
            var destination = File.Create("encrypted.tmp");
            string path = source.Name;

            using (var provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            using (var transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(key, IV))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(destination, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // Encrypts file
                source.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                source.Close();

                // Deletes unencrypted file
                File.Delete(path);
            }
            // Replaces source file with encrypted file
            destination.Close();
            File.Move(destination.Name, path);
            File.Delete(destination.Name);
        }
```

But when I use this to decrypt the file, the file will be empty:

```
        private void tempDecrypt()
        {
            // Opens encrypted file
            var file = File.OpenRead("test.txt");
            var temp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            temp.Key = System.Convert.FromBase64String("SANeQe1MK4UKrQmJ4fa16lrhIexK7gaxqE/N/HycdhI=");
            temp.IV = System.Convert.FromBase64String("Pb2SciISBP2p0hWzEUG05A==");
            Encryptor.Decrypt(file, temp.Key, temp.IV);
        }

        public static void Decrypt(FileStream source, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Creates a temp file for decrypting
            var destination = File.Create("decrypted.tmp");
            string path = source.Name;

            Console.WriteLine(source.Length);

            // Decrypts rest of file
            using (var provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            using (var transform = provider.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(source, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                // Decrypts file
                cryptoStream.CopyTo(destination);
            }
            // Replaces source file with decrypted file
            destination.Close();
            source.Close();
            File.Delete(path);
            File.Move(destination.Name, path);
            File.Delete(destination.Name);
        }
```

Replacing the file doesn't seem to be the problem because even "decrypted.tmp" is empty before I replace the destination file with the source one.

Comment: You're certain that `test.txt` isn't empty?

Comment: @canton7 I guess the file it was encrypting was still empty even after writing to it. Closing and re-opening the file solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tempEncrypt() method, I had to close the file then re-open using File.OpenRead() for it to decrypt properly. I guess test.txt was still empty even though I used file.Write() to write to the file. Here is the working method:

```
        private void tempEncrypt()
        {
            // Creates file with "Test String" inside
            byte[] test = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test String");
            var file = File.Create("test.txt");
            file.Write(test, 0, test.Length);
            
            file.Close();
            var newFile = File.OpenRead("test.txt");

            // Saves key and IV for decryption
            var temp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(temp.Key));
            Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToBase64String(temp.IV));

            Encryptor.Encrypt(newFile, temp.Key, temp.IV);
        }
```

Comment: The key and IV in decrypt has to be the same as the one used to Encrypt.

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot that you were writing to the `FileStream`, and then immediately reading from it. Streams have a position, which indicates where in the stream you are. When you open the file, the stream's position is at the start of the file. When you write some data to the file, the position is advanced to just past the end of that data. When you read from a stream, it reads from the current position. So the `Encrypt` method read the data to encrypt from a point just beyond the position where the data finished! You can set the stream's position back to 0 explicitly if you need